# Proof: If $A \subset X$ a topological space and $p \in cl(A) - A$, then every open set containing $p$ intersects $A.$

Tags: general-topology

I don't understand the proof of this theorem. Here is a reference http://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/jabuka/Classes/2004_fall/Handouts/03%20-%20Congergent%20sequences.pdf page 3.

In particular, if for contradiction $U$ is an open set containing $p$ and $A \cap U = \emptyset$, then $cl(A) - U$ is closed - **why is this set closed** ?

Help would be appreciated

---

Thanks for answers and especially comment explaining why the set is closed.
I now understand the theorem as follows:

**Basic set theory**:  If A, B ⊂ X, then A\B = A ∩ (X\B).

Proof:
A ∩ (X\B) = { x ∊ A and (x ∊ X and x ∉ B)} = { x ∊ A and x ∉ B} = A\B

**Basic Topology**: if C ⊂ X is a closed set and O ⊂ X an open set then 
C\O is closed and O\C is open.

Proof: 
C\O = C ∩ (X\O) and X\O is the complement of an open set therefore closed. So C\O is the intersection of two closed sets and is closed.

O\C = O ∩ (X\C) and X\C is the complement of a closed set therefore open. So O\C is the intersection of two open sets, and is open.

**The theorem**:

Proof:
Note that if S is closed then cl(S)\S = {} and there is no such p and therefore no such U. So the statement is vacuously true.
Otherwise, ...

**cl(S)\U is a closed set** (= closed\open).

Suppose p ∊ cl(S)\S  and p ∊ U  an open set.

Since p ∊ cl(S)\S then p ∊ cl(S), and p ∊ U so p ∉ cl(S)\U.

Therefore cl(S)\U is a proper subset of cl(S). I.e. **cl(S) ⊄ cl(S)\U**

But cl(S) is the intersection of all closed sets containing S, and therefore  a subset of any closed set containing S.

Therefore cl(S) ⊄ cl(S)\U together with  cl(S)\U is a closed set $\implies$ **S ⊄ cl(S)\U**

But S ⊂  cl(S) (and S ⊄ cl(S)\U) so **U ∩ S ≠ {}**

Comment: It is closed since it is the intersection of two closed sets, namely $cl(A)$ and $X \setminus U$.

Comment: @Crostul - ah ! Follows I think from a general result that $ A-B = A \cap (X-B)$ - yes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of closed sets is closed and $\operatorname{cl}(A)\setminus U=\operatorname{cl}(A)\cap(X\setminus U)$, where $X\setminus U$ is closed.

However, there's a simpler proof that doesn't use contradiction.

Let $p\in\operatorname{cl}(A)$ and let $U$ be an open set such that $p\in U$. Since $U$ is a neighborhood of $p$, we know by definition of closure that
$$
A\cap U\ne\emptyset
$$
Let $x\in A\cap U$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\ne p$, because $p\notin A$ by assumption.

Answer (score 1):

$a\in cl(A)-A$, $a\in U$, $U$ open $A\cap U$ is empty implies $X-U$ is closed and contains $A$ this implies that $X-U$ contains $cl(A)$ contradiction since it does not contain $a$.